# How to make system() in R print all console output?

Tags: r

I'm cloning a git repo in R with

`system("git clone git@git.server:team_name/repo_name.git ~/dev/", invisible = FALSE)`

and this works, but in R, it only prints the initial message

`Cloning into 'repo_name'`

and doesn't print the progress like below

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 48398 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 48397
Receiving objects: 100% (48398/48398), 149.14 MiB | 647.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (24365/24365), done.
Checking out files: 100% (7182/7182), done.
```

How can I make the system() function print all the output as it is being printed?